# firebase real database Removing child element react native

Tags: react-native

I want to remove the child element from firebase real time database. My firebase looks like this.

```
employees:{
  employee1:{
   about:{
    name: 'John'
   }
  }
employee2:{
   about:{
     name: 'sam'
    }
 }

}
```

I want to remove sam from `employees/employee2/about/name`. How can I do that? Help please

Comment: Do you want to replace it with an empty string or remove the field entirely?

Comment: Is there anyway to just remove sam from employee two. Like I just want to remove the name from employee to. Thanks for replying

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

To remove the field entirely:

`firebase.database().ref("employees/employee2/about/name").remove()`

To replace it with an empty string:

`firebase.database().ref("employees/employee2/about/name").set("")`